# how to save data from HDD protected by true crypt password?

Tags: windows

Using True Crypt password on clients computer. How to save data from HDD protected by a true cryp password using windows, while the windows crushed?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the encryption key, you can remove the hard disk and mount the drive on another machine with TrueCrypt installed.